# FROM Http Header not included unless it's a valid email address

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, http, asp.net-web-api, http-headers

I'm using the [Advanced Rest Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo) Chrome extension to test a request to a Web API 2 endpoint. I'm trying to include a value in the "From" header but the value is null when it is not a valid email address. [By reading the spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.22), it looks like it only SHOULD be a valid email address, not that it MUST. Is this something that is happening because of Web API, Chrome, the extension, or something else?

Comment: Can you post your server side code that is seeing the null header? I doubt it's a server side issue or a Chrome issue. Possibly the extension. It's most likely the code used to pull the header value out. Have you looked at the entire request? You can try using Fiddler (http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to see if it works from there if that works, it's either the extension or Chrome. You can also use Wireshark (https://www.wireshark.org/) to see the actual bytes going through your NIC.

Comment: @ManOVision, I used Fiddler and can see that the header is being sent to the server so I'm pretty sure the problem is there. I ended up using a custom header to work around this, but I'll leave the question up here in case anyone has any insight as to why this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your comment about Fiddler seeing the header, I was curious so I did a little test. Here is my controller code:

```
public class FromController : ApiController
{
    [Route("api/from")]
    public dynamic Get()
    {
        string from1 = null;
        string from2 = null;
        string from3 = null;

        from1 = this.Request.Headers.From;

        IEnumerable<string> headers;
        if (this.Request.Headers.TryGetValues("From", out headers))
        {
            from2 = headers.FirstOrDefault();
        }

        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers.AllKeys.Contains("From"))
        {
            from3 = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["From"];
        }

        var output = new
        {
            From1 = from1,
            From2 = from2,
            From3 = from3
        };

        return output;
    }
}
```

Test 1: Send **e@test.com** as the From header outputs:

```
{
    "From1": "e@test.com",
    "From2": "e@test.com",
    "From3": "e@test.com"
}
```

Everything is as expected.

Test 2: Send **junk** as the From header outputs:

```
{
    "From1": null,
    "From2": "junk",
    "From3": "junk"
}
```

This shows your findings of the header being null, but you can get it via the other methods.

Internally it's running some parsing on the values. The value is stored in an invalid container so asking for it directly results in null. By asking via TryGetValue, it ignores any "helpful" parsing so you'll get the value.

I added the old HttpContext.Current.Request just to see since this is more raw form, but I'd steer clear from using this in production and try to stick with this.Request for anything while in a Controller.  I like to use HttpContext.Current.Request.SaveAs(fileName, true) to see what the actual raw request is. I did this first and saw the header so I knew it had to be accessible somehow.